# Converting types that are part of a union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Say I want to create a type from another type but change all `number`s to `string`s.

This for example:

```js
type NumberToString<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? string : T[K]
}
```

will work for an input:

```js
type T = {
  num: number,
}

// works, creates new type { num: string }
type NewType = NumberToString<T1>;
```

but will fail if the `number` is part of a union like 'number | null'

```js
type T = {
  maybeNum: number | null,
}

// not working as I expect
type NewType = NumberToString<T>;
```

Expected this

```js
type T = { maybeNum: string | null }
```

Got this

```js
type T = { maybeNum: number | null }
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwEYQE4BUD2BlYqCWAdgOYA86AfFALxQDeAsAFBRQDaA0lEVANYQhMAMyjoAugC5RnMVAgAPYBEIATAM5RCiFKigB+KGrxFiUKehnMAvs2ahIogIw16zVloRSPOgDTXbTAD0gVAA7piovGo+UADGqBAAhkoahBChUPbQdJqIUkYEJFA2TFmw6ejg0LTwyGhYuIVk6I4UANwBZegATC6MLFAIiSAotV7aaFAAPrkANrN+TCXMwZqYwGERvCYx8UkpmVX0g8Ojebl1ujNa88UrIaEAFslQAJJhiYQb+Bo5QyMQMaGYxFa5wW4lMowCpVXo1CYYHAg5rddpAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the `extends` the other way, then add in the types that aren't `number`:

```
type NumberToString<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: number extends T[K] ? string | Exclude<T[K], number> : T[K]
};
```

However, number literal types don't work anymore:

```
type T = NumberToString<{ foo: 0 }> // { foo: 0 } instead of { foo: string }
```

but if you need this, lemme know and I'll edit in a workaround.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mq322w)

Comment: genius, I don't understand how `number` extends `number | null` can be true but I'll do some reading...

Comment: @Nic `A extends B` is just checking if `A` is assignable to `B`. Imagine you have a variable that is a `number`. Of course you can assign it to something that can be `number` or `null`. However, you can't do the opposite.